# How to highlight multiple countries on Google Maps using fusion table

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to highlight multiple countries on Google Maps, but I am a little bit confused about the query. It works on a single country, e.g., if I highlight Mexico it works, but when try to highlight Mexico *and* India it does not work.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4PANk/10/)

I have tried the code below, but it is not working

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {select: "kml_4326", 
          from: tableid,
          where: "name_0 = 'Mexico' and name_0 = 'India'"},
  styles: [{
  polygonOptions: {
    strokeWeight: "0",
    //strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: "0.4",
    fillOpacity: "2",
    fillColor: "#FF0000"

  }
}]});
```

The code is working for a single country.

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {select: "kml_4326", 
          from: tableid,
          where: "name_0 = 'Mexico'"},
  styles: [{
  polygonOptions: {
    strokeWeight: "0",
    //strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: "0.4",
    fillOpacity: "2",
    fillColor: "#FF0000"

  }
}]});
```

Also I have tried the code below as a Google Document refrence from [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-styling), but it highlights the whole map.

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'kml_4326',
      from: tableid
    },
    styles: [{
      polygonOptions: {
        //fillColor: '#00FF00',
       // fillOpacity: 0.3
      }
    }, {
      where: 'name_0 == India',
      polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: '#000'
      }
    }, {
      where: 'name_0 == Mexico',
      polygonOptions: {
        fillOpacity: 1.0,
        fillColor: '#00FF00'
      }
    }]
  });

  layer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_MultiCountryBrowser.html?countries=Afghanistan,Albania,Algeria,United%20States%20of%20America,Brazil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your select statement to:

```
query: {select: "kml_4326", 
          from: tableid,
          where: "name_0 IN ('Mexico','India')"
       },
```

Comment: do you know how to zoom on specific  country if i have two option on in my web page india and maxico if click on india and maxico.

Comment: If you create a draggable marker, instead of clicking a country you could drag the marker to it and trigger a `dragend` function to re-center the map and zoom in.